# Update table to not IN condition

Tags: linq

I have a strongly typed list called "attendeeList" that contains all active attendees:

```
   List<tb_Attendees> attendeeList

   public partial class tb_Attendees
   {
    public int AttendeeId { get; set; }
    public int MeetingId { get; set; }
    public string AttendeeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    .....
```

I need update the following table:

```
    DataContext.tb_Attendees
```

such that that for a given MeetingId, for all AttendeeIds are not in the list, it will update those records to IsActive = false. Basically I am doing a NOT IN.

I want to do something to the effect:

```
 DataContext.tb_Attendees.Where(p => p.MeetingId == meetingId && !attendeeList.Contains(p => p.AttendId) ).ToList().ForEach(x => x.IsActive = false);
 DataContext.SaveChanges();
```

First of all, is this correct? I get an error saying cannot convert from int to Model.tb_Attendees. Do I need to have the list as in int list or any way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You're close, but it sounds like you need a list of *IDs*, not a list of attendees:

```
var attendeeIDList = attendeeList.Select(a => a.AttendId);

DataContext.tb_Attendees
           .Where(p => p.MeetingId == meetingId 
                    && !attendeeIDList.Contains(p => p.AttendId) )
           .ToList()
           .ForEach(x => x.IsActive = false);
```

I would also note that the `ForEach` is just syntactic sugar and would be functionally equivalent to:

```
foreach(var x in
     DataContext.tb_Attendees
                .Where(p => p.MeetingId == meetingId 
                         && !attendeeIDList.Contains(p => p.AttendId) ))
{
    x.IsActive = false;
}
```